# Состояние store в Redux не накапливается

Tags: redux, reactjs

Помогите разобраться почему состояние store не накапливается. Делаю twitter-like приложение. В store хочу добавлять посты. А store постоянно сбрасывает своё состояние. Не соображу где для этого нужно подправить код.
Ведь в офиц доках пишут: (previousState, action) => newState, правда там store хранится в массиве, а не в литерале, как у меня:
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html

Моё приложение целиком здесь:
https://github.com/SkunSHD/redux-twitter-like-app/tree/master

Код reducer'a выглядит так:
reducers/page.js

```js
import { 
  ADD_POST,
  ADD_COMMENT,
  LOGIN_SUCCES
} from '../constants/Page'

const initialState = {
  user: '',
  text: ''
}

export default function page(state = initialState, action) {

  switch (action.type) {
    case LOGIN_SUCCES:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload }

    case ADD_POST:
      return { ...state, user: state.user, text: action.payload }

    case ADD_COMMENT:
      return { ...state, user: action.payload.user, text: action.payload.text }

    default:
      return state;
  }

}
```

actions/PageActions:

```js
import {
  ADD_POST,
  ADD_COMMENT
} from '../constants/Page'

export function addPost(text) {

  return (dispatch) => {
dispatch({
  type: ADD_POST,
  payload: text
})
   
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В редьюсере, вот в этом месте:

```
case ADD_POST:
  return { ...state, user: state.user, text: action.payload }
```

вы изменяете состояние, state.text становится равным action.payload, т.е. тому тексту, который вы добавляете через функцию addPost. Чтобы и старые значения оставались, надо добавлять , а не перезаписывать, например:

```
 return { ...state, user: state.user, text: state.text + action.payload }
```